# How to get a logo in ./app/console like the one composer has?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, console-application

I have created for my symfony2 application a bunch of commands. If I just run the console, I see the rather unexciting:

```
$ ./app/console 
Symfony version 3.0.4-DEV - app/dev/debug
```

If you run composer you'll see an ASCII art logo and the name and version of the application itself.

```
$composer
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
Composer version 1.0.2 2016-04-21 12:30:18
```

How did they achieve that? As they are using the symfony2 console components. I looked through the commands, yet I did not find the place where it is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not in the commands but in composer's [`Application.php`](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.0/src/Composer/Console/Application.php) that just extends `Symfony\Component\Console\Application` and there they set the logo:

```
class Application extends BaseApplication
{
    private static $logo = '   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
';

    public function getHelp()
    {
        return self::$logo . parent::getHelp();
    }
}
```

---

So I did just the same. I have created my own

```
MyApplication extends Application
{
    private static $name = "MyAPP";
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $logo = <<<LOGO
               ,:',:`,:'
            __||_||_||_||__
       ____["""""""""""""""]____
       \ " '''''''''''''''''''' |
~^~^~^^~^~^~^~^~^~^~^~~^~^~^^~~^~^~^~^

LOGO;

    /**
     * MyApp constructor.
     * @param KernelInterface $kernel
     * @param string          $version
     */
    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel, $version)
    {
        parent::__construct($kernel);
        $this->setName(static::$name);
        $this->setVersion($version);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHelp()
    {
        return static::$logo . parent::getHelp();
    }
}
```

and used that in my `app/console`:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
$application = new MyApplication($kernel, '1.0.2');
$application->run($input);
```

---

And now `$ ./app/console/` prints:

```
               ,:',:`,:'
            __||_||_||_||__
       ____["""""""""""""""]____
       \ " '''''''''''''''''''' |
~^~^~^^~^~^~^~^~^~^~^~~^~^~^^~~^~^~^~^
MyAPP version 1.0.2
```